# Details on Makefiles

Tags: c, makefile

I am learning about Makefiles and when I first searched the web I did not get any response regarding my question(s).

What are the `-o`, `-f`, `-c`, `-g`, `-Wall`, `-I`, etc. actually called (like +, --, ||, && are called operators), so I can do a correct search on them in the future, and what do they do?

An example I found where this occurs in a Makefile is shown below:

```
helloworld : helloworld.c
    gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c

hellomake: hellomake.c hellofunc.c
     gcc -o hellomake hellomake.c hellofunc.c -I.

all: myprog.c
     gcc -g -Wall -o myprog myprog.c
```

(Note: they are parts taken from other Makefiles examples just to show where the "-g", "-Wall", etc. were used

Comment: You should start with GNU make documentation first. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with Makefiles in particular (or C), but with shell scripting (makefiles just execute a bunch of shell commands). Those are called *arguments* and often the arguments which don't take a value are called *flags*.

Answer (score 2):

Those flags have nothing to do with make per se.  Make is a program that exists to run *other* programs.  Most commonly, but not solely, compilers.

Those flags are flags for your compiler (`gcc` in this case).  So you should be looking at the documentation for your compiler to understand what they do.

Make just runs the commands you give it.  You won't find compiler flags in the documentation for make any more than you would in the documentation for your shell, even though you can run the compiler from your shell.

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two different things.  All a makefile does is define a set of commands you can use to shorten a command line call using the program Make.  So, in your example, "make helloworld" will call "helloworld.c gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c" on the command line, where "make all" will call "myprog.c gcc -g -Wall -o myprog myprog.c".  On the other hand, the program gcc has different command line arguments (such as -o) which tell the program to run a certain way.  -Wall, for example, tells it to output all warnings, even trivial ones.

Answer (score 1):

Those are command line flags. The flags you're referring to appear to be flags to gcc (your C compiler).

Much of a Makefile consists of what are essentially shell commands. The "`gcc -g -Wall -o myprog myprog.c`" is an example of this. You could type the same command in your shell (ie: in a terminal) to do the same thing. What make does is figure out the right time to execute these commands, and it also make it possible to come up with generalized rule (eg: "this is how I always compile .c files into .o files").

Answer (score 0):

```
"-o", "-f", "-c", "-g", "-Wall", "-I",
```

Are all options of the Compiler, it's nothing to to with Make. Read the compiler man page.

```
man gcc
```